# Enumerate List with Different Base number

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

Some old tests around here had questions that consisted in analyzing several items (each with a different number associated with it) and adding up the numbers of all the correct ones. To avoid having multiple combinations giving the same answers like `1+3 = 4` and `4=4`, the numbers are all powers of 2, so:

```
01. This is the first item (2⁰)
02. This is the second item (2¹)
04. This is the third item (2²)
08. This is the forth item (2³)
16. This is the fifth item (2⁴)
```

So my goal is to recreate this kind of enumerating list, that follows the powers of 2 (0 -- 1 -- 2 -- 4 -- 8 -- 16 -- 32 and so on). Is there a package that can do it or a rather simple way around it? In the document I currently am working on I am using the `enumitem` package, already.

Comment: Are the trailing `0` important?

Comment: I'd like them to keep everything with 2 digits, although they could be dropped if the solution would get too complicated

Comment: I think, this can be achieved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An 'awful' mix with `enumitem` and `expl3` features, defining a new `counter formater` named `baseenum`  -- I've to test with deeper level nesting however.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter


\def\basetwoenum#1{\expandafter\@basetwoenum\csname c@#1\endcsname}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\@basetwoenum#1{%
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int \c_one
  \int_step_inline:nnnn {2}{1}{\number#1}{%
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int { 2 * \l_tmpa_int }
    \int_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_int \l_tmpb_int
  }
  \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\AddEnumerateCounter{\basetwoenum}{\@basetwoenum}{100}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\basetwoenum*}]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Fourth
  \item Fifth
\end{enumerate}

Resume it

\begin{enumerate}[label={\basetwoenum*},resume]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Fourth
  \item Fifth
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In your answer, I see the line `\int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int { 2 * \l_tmpa_int }`. Is this what defines "power of 2" to be used? Switching that `2 *` to a `n *` would allow me to use whatever power of `n` I chose?

Comment: @GuilhermeVargas: Yes, but in this case I would suggest some other setup, to make it more user - friendly

Comment: Something like in the other answer that is a variant to your solution? Just curious

Comment: @GuilhermeVargas: Well, egreg did provide for expansion -- if you need `\label` or `\ref` his solution is better, of course

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\renewcommand*{\labelenumi}{\pgfmathparse{int(2^(\theenumi-1))} \pgfmathresult}


\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item One
        \item Two
        \item Three
        \item more
        \item more
        \item more
        \item more
        \item more
        \item more
        \item more
        \item more
        \item more
        \item more
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a couple of descriptive sentences that explain the main aspects of your solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution, which works with the `enumitem` package. It defines an enumerated environment called `powertwoenum`, in which consecutive items are numbered as 1, 2, 4, 8, 32, etc. Items in a `powertwoenum` list may be cross-referenced via the usual `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\powertwo{\directlua{tex.sprint(2^(\arabic{powertwoenumi}-1))}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{powertwoenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[powertwoenum]{label=\protect\powertwo.,ref=\protect\powertwo}


\begin{document}
\begin{powertwoenum}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Fourth
  \item Fifth \label{item:five}
\end{powertwoenum}

A cross-reference to item \ref{item:five}.

Resume the enumerated list.

\begin{powertwoenum}[resume]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Fourth
  \item Fifth
\end{powertwoenum}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A variant of Christian Hupfer's solution, but fully expandable:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\basetwoenum}{m}
 {
  \basetwoenum_main:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \basetwoenum_main:n
 {
  \exp_args:Nc \basetwoenum_eval:n { c@#1 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \basetwoenum_eval:n
 {
  \fp_eval:n { 2 ** (#1-1) }
 }
%% for keeping enumitem happy
\cs_set_eq:cN { @basetwoenum } \basetwoenum_main:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\AddEnumerateCounter{\basetwoenum}{\@basetwoenum}{000}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\basetwoenum*}]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Fourth
  \item Fifth
\end{enumerate}

Resume it

\begin{enumerate}[label={\basetwoenum*},resume]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Fourth
  \item Fifth
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This gives correct results up to 2<sup>53</sup>; of course, if you plan to use more than ten items you have to accordingly increase the number of zeros in the final argument to `\AddEnumerateCounter`.

[image]

Comment: Is an expandable solution really an issue here? If the O.P. requires values to be used in other macros )or calculation, I see the point, of course, but for mere typesetting?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\label` and `\ref`?

Comment: Agreed!!!!!!!!!!!!!